# Python using grep from os.system adds "0" line to variable?

Tags: python, grep

I'm running grep from within a python script like so:

`last_run_start = os.system("cat %(file)s | grep '[0-24]:[0-59]' | tail -n1" % locals())`

Which pulls out the last timestamp in `file`. When I do this through the Python command line, or use that grep command through regular terminal, I get what would be expected - the last line containing a timestamp.

However, when run from this script `last_run_start` is returning this:

```
18:23:45

0
```

Whats causing this '0' to appear, let alone on a new line? More importantly, how can I remove it from `last_run_start`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os#os.system) returns the exit code of the command you've run, which in this case seems to be 0.

The output of the command goes directly to `stdout` and isn't stored in `last_run_start`, if you want that you should use `Popen` or `check_output` from the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess) module.

I guess the `0` ends up being printed because you're printing `last_run_start` somwhere.